# Uwanted change of a session value by ajax executed php script

Tags: php, ajax, session

Hey I just found out that I have a bug on my website.
I have something like facebook wall on the website and retrieving older post is done by ajax from external php file.
I use SQL limit to get older post and it looks like this

```
SELECT ... LIMIT $_SESSION['page'],20;
$_SESSION['page']=$_SESSION['page']+1;
```

It works fine for 2 or 4 clicks on "Show older posts" and then $_SESSION['page'] hase value 1 again.
Can you help me please ?

Comment: The only condition $_SESSION['page'] has value 1 again  **if** $_SESSION['page'] set to zero

Comment: But the only thing done by the script loaded by ajax is that it increments $_SESSION['page'] by 1 but somehow it changes the the vale itself

Comment: can you edit the script code into your question

Answer (score 0):

You should bever use such a value as the page number in a session... What of your user uses a second tab to access the same page? Unexpected behavior can occur.. Instead of setting and modifying the pagenumber in yoursession, put iit in the URL of your ajax call and use $_GET to read its value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didnt fix my problem, I just found out that after fourth click on "Show older posts" it unsets the session and creates a new one with value 1

Comment: Nice to see you found your issue, especcially as we dont see any such code posted:) I do suggest to change the usage of Session to URL Params.

Comment: But it still doesnt work, Id say that it should work with sessions as well